# Spring Reactor Set of Sets Combine to a Set

Tags: java-8, java-stream, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to figure out how to get a `Mono<Set<Customer>>` from `Flux<Order>` .

Given that Order contains `Set<Customer>`

I've been trying to read all over and here is the closest i can get but it still wont compile. Can someone offer a hand please. In following example, orderService.getAll(orderCriteria) returns `Flux<Order>`

```
final Mono<Set<Customer>> customerSetMono = orderService
              .getAll(orderCriteria)
              .map(order -> order.getCustomers())
              .collect(Collectors.toSet()) //Mono<Set<Set<Customer>>
              .flatMap(
                  customerSet -> customerSet.stream()
                      .flatMap(customers -> customers.stream()))
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: what stream does `orderService.getAll(orderCriteria)` return? looks like `.flatMap(order -> order.getCustomers().stream())` should be it.

Comment: so getAll() returns Flux of Order

Comment: final Mono<Set< Customer >> customerSetMono = orderService
              .getAll(orderCriteria)
              .flatMap(order -> order. getCustomers().stream())
              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
also did not compile

Comment: `orderService.getAll(orderCriteria).map(order -> order.getCustomers()).flatMapIterable(customers -> customers).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: Much shorter form - `orderService.getAll(orderCriteria).flatMapIterable(Order::getCustomers).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're facing a `list` inside a `list` scenario but in a reactive context. So, all you need to do is use a proper variant of `flatMap`. Here's how your code should look like

```java
orderService.getAll(orderCriteria) // Flux<Order>
        .flatMapIterable(Order::getCustomers) // Flux<Customer>
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Mono<Set<Customer>>
```

Comment: thanks can you pls elaborate why we cannot use streams way